# Decline a string in a string variable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console, console-application

I need to decline the ability to write strings in my console application, at the moment, when text is entered instead of numbers, the console crashes.

I have something along the lines of this right now

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names = new string[2];
        string age;
        bool agetest = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello, I am the NameBot2000, What is your first name?");
        names[0] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Well done. What is your surname?");
        names[1] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What year were you born in?");
        age = Console.ReadLine();

        int.Parse(age);

        if (Enumerable.Range(0,2015).Contains(age));




        int year = 0;


        string wow = "";

        if (Enumerable.Range(0,31).Contains(year))
            wow = "young";

        else if (Enumerable.Range(31,51).Contains(year)) 
            wow = "old";

        else if (Enumerable.Range(51,500).Contains(year))
            wow = "ancient";

        Console.WriteLine("Well done. You said your name was {0} {1}, and you are {2} years old!", names[0], names[1], year);
        Console.WriteLine("You are so {0}!", wow);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
```

I have tried to incorporate a boolean but I am unsure how to compare the variable to check which format it is in.

Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-parse

Comment: There are a *lot* of problems with this code, so it's hard to determine exactly which one you're asking about. Can you shrink this down to a small snippet which demonstrates your exact problem?

Comment: `int.Parse(age);` is not going to do anything. save its result in `int`. `int iage=int.Parse(age);`

Comment: `if (Enumerable.Range(0,2015).Contains(age));` is not going to do anything. the semicolon after `if` is empty line of code. you didnt use scope (`{   }`) hence it does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `Parse`, use `TryParse`.

```
int age = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(Console.Readline, out age)
    // Correct format.
else
    // error!
```

What `TryParse()` will do, is take the user input, **Try** to **Parse** it to an int, and if successful, will output an int (and a `bool = true`), otherwise it will output a `bool = false`.

Answer (score 0):

use a try catch

```
string age = console.readline();
bool validage = false;
While(!validage)
{
    try
    {
        int myage = int.parse(age);
        validage = true;
    }
    catch 
    {
        console.write("Please Enter an Integer value for age:");
        age = console.readline();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to use tryparse which takes care of error handling for you.

Comment: yeah that can work,   however i wanted to be able to give a notification to the user and prompt for a new input,  tryparse would also work if you just wanted to throw an error and move on.

Comment: You can check for a false return from tryparse then do something with it, like Ben's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check ConsoleKeyInfo to make sure user can only enter digits for age.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Age : ");
ConsoleKeyInfo key;
string ageStr = "";
do
{
    key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(key.KeyChar))//Check if it is a number
        {
            ageStr += key.KeyChar;
            Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && ageStr.Length > 0)
        {
            ageStr = ageStr.Substring(0, (ageStr.Length - 1));
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
    }
} 
while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

Console.WriteLine("Age is {0}", ageStr);
```